# How to design study to predict development of a condition B given a condition A

Tags: epidemiology, research-design, case-cohort

***Overall aim:***

I have patients with a very common condition and I want to see if it is significantly associated with a reduction in a certain type of cancer between 6 months to 5 years later when compared to a population that does not have this common condition.

*****Method:*****

I have 1000 patients with condition A and about 7000 with no condition A. I haven't tried to match them as yet as I wasn't sure I needed to. I also know who has developed the cancer of interest within that time frame

***My questions are:***

I am assuming this is a type of retrospective cohort study which should give a relative risk or odds ratio calculation between the two (with chi-square test of independence for significance?)

1. Am I correct in saying this is a retrospective cohort study with
   relative risk or odds ratio being the outcome metric of interest.
2. Do my groups need to be balanced either in size or matched
   (age/sex/other).